# meaning of "bodies"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "bodies" mean in this sentence?

> O Sol,...whose approaching and receding makes the four seasons, necessary of the ripening of the harvest, and the temperature of the bodies.

Does it mean "celestial bodies" or human bodies?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a literary interpretation of a piece of writing.

Comment: It's not clear at all. It could be one or the other or something else. But none of them seem good.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the sentence is from [*The Collected Works of Eric Voegelin. Vol. 23, Religion and the Rise of Modernity*](http://www.portalconservador.com/livros/Eric-Voegelin-History-of-Political-Ideas-Vol.V.pdf) (PDF link) by Eric Voegelin.

Following is more context:

> The characteristic Mediterranean atmosphere can perhaps best be felt in the sigh of Louis Le Roy, his great contemporary to whom he owes [more than a] little: "O Heaven, by the continued movement and influence of which divine providence rules and incessantly restores and renews in France an incredible abundance and insatiable variety of all things; O Sol, father of time, warmth and light, whose approaching and receding makes the four seasons, necessary for the ripening of the harvest, and the temperature of the bodies; O Luna, Lady of the humors, mother of all growth; O Planets and other Stars who assist in their effects on the Elements and on that which they engender: do you cause and sustain in France this temperateness of air, this fertility of water and earth, multitude of all sorts of grains, fruits, animals, plants, in order that the French starve and destroy one another?"

The entire passage is talking about the effects of the divine (and the heavens) on the nature of earthly things in France—or at least the Mediterranean in general.

The term **the bodies** is listed along with "the harvest" and a "multitude of all sorts of grains, fruits, animals, plants."

It's not clear what the exact referent is, but it seems likely that it's talking about something along with all of the other things in the area that the divine and the heavens affect.

Since there is specific reference to the four seasons and "the temperature of the bodies," and a further section that says (emphasis mine), "O Planets and other Stars who assist in their effects on the Elements and on that which they engender: do you cause and sustain in France this temperateness of **air**, this fertility of **water and earth**," my best guess is that **the bodies** refers to bodies of air, water, and earth—in particular, those of France.